# sql combine only some duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine one set of duplicates from my table, but not all.

example:

```
acct    date     bal
--------------------
123   1/1/2013   40.00
123   1/1/2013   2.00
456   1/2/2013   50.00
456   1/1/2013   5.00
789   1/1/2013   10.00
789   1/1/2013   17.00
```

I would like to combine acct 123 to only one row, summing the balance of those rows, but leave the rest.

desired output:

```
acct    date     bal
--------------------
123   1/1/2013   42.00
456   1/2/2013   50.00
456   1/1/2013   5.00
789   1/1/2013   10.00
789   1/1/2013   17.00
```

Working in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Do you want to combine only the first duplicate row? Or on a particular date? Or on a particular acct? With what logic do you want to combine them?

Comment: I want to combine on a particular acct. Summing the balance and pulling the highest date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CASE in GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT acct, date, SUM(bal) AS bal
FROM dbo.tets73
GROUP BY acct, date, CASE WHEN acct != 123 THEN bal END
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebf2/2/0)

Comment: This worked for the data I used in my example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko this is it - :D You got it all right, coz there has to be a simpler better way than union, that's what I was trying for ;) +1 This becomes one of my favourite answers!

Comment: @bonCodigo tnx. I saw your answer, it was very close to the purpose;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT acct, date, SUM(bal)
FROM T
WHERE acct = 123

UNION

SELECT acct, date, bal
FROM T
WHERE acct <> 123
```

Comment: and Alex whatever you said is true. That was one ridiculous piece of code... +1, simplicity pays off most of the time as the opposite likely to miss the obvious ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 select acct, date, sum(bal) from table where acct = 123
 union
 select acct, date bal from table where acct <> 123
```